# How to check if a facebook id is valid

Tags: php, facebook

I have a script which will generate random numbers like **1000089838938** but I need a solution to check if the generated number is associated with a valid facebook account.

Solution I am looking for should be in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just hit the graph api and see if it returns valid data, (ie, no error page or a page with just the word "false")?

Comment: Why are you generating the number in the first place ?

Comment: All answers so far suggested hitting the API with the ID, but I think you will not get a response (or just the very useful “unsupported GET request” message) for users that have disabled apps altogether – because they are not “visible” _at all_ to apps. (And what you would need this for anyway, I’m still wondering?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to check ID after generating via Graph API.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[ID]
```

whatever ID is generated, put that at end of URL and check response received. Like if ID is 1303834107

you can check @ `http://graph.facebook.com/1303834107`

If it's correct, response will be something like:

```
{
  "id": "1303834107",
  "name": "John Flake",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Flake",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/john.flake",
  "username": "john.flake",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US"
}
```

or if that ID is invalid, you will get something like:

```
{
 "error": 
  {
  "message": "Unsupported get request.",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
  }
}
```

Based on response, you can validate that ID.

Use php curl to call each time the API URL when ID is generated to check the response.

Comment: "An access token is required to request this resource."

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy:

Just make a curl call from your php to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1457691266/
```

Replace this with any ID - 1000089838938

If you get a json in response then the ID is valid else you will get unsupported get request. :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: "An access token is required to request this resource."

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$url = get_data("https://graph.facebook.com/+".$id."'");
$id = json_decode($url, true);
$id = $id['data'][0]['username'];
```

$id gives you user name of id posted.